# Proving a property of a linear operator and its adjoint if they commute

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, invariant-subspace

Let $F = \mathbb{C}$

Let V be a finite-dimensional complex vector space equipped with a positive definite sesquilinear form $\phi$. Let $\alpha$ be a linear operator on $V$, and denote its unique adjoint with respect to $\phi$ by $\alpha^{*}$. Prove the following statements are equivalent:

(a)  $\alpha$ is normal

(b)$ \alpha = \alpha_{1}+i\alpha_{2}$ for some self adjoint(with respect to $\phi$ linear operators $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ on $V$ such that $\alpha_1\circ\alpha_2 = \alpha_2\circ\alpha_1$

(c) $ \alpha^*= g(\alpha)$ for some $g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$

Now for a) ==> c) I have the result that I can use , if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linear operators on $V$, $\alpha$ satisfies a polynomial in field $F$, $V$ is $\alpha$-cyclic, then  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute iff $B= p(a)$ for some polynomial in the field $F$. But afterwards I am just stuck.

Comment: Ok so I have a result, that the eigenspace of $\alpha$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ equals the eigenspace of $ad(\alpha)$ with eigenvalue $\bar{\lambda}$. So we can split the space V into the direct sum of each eigenspace, and then since the restriction of $\alpha$ to each eigenspace is alpha invariant, and the gcd of the min polynomials restricted to each eigenspace is $x-\lambda$, we can go from 1 to 3 and vice versa. I have no idea how to go from $1 \to 2$ though